# Android screen before calling main activity

Tags: android, view, android-activity, screen

I'm developing an application for Android 4.x and realized that I have a black screen with the default action bar a second before my main screen is loaded.

Anyone had this problem before? It's possible to dismiss it or show a different "default" screen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you have the remnants of a "theme" from Eclipse?

Comment: A theme from Eclipse? The one that appears when you create an empty layout resource? If so yes.

Answer (score 0):

To specify which activity you want to load first, in your AndroidManifest.xml, put this in its `<activity>`:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
```

For example:

```
<activity
         android:name=".MainActivity"
         android:label="@string/app_name" >
         <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Yes, I'm doing like that to call my main activity. But the problem is still happening.

Comment: @user1683087 I don't understand, is a different theme loading first before your preferred theme loads?

Comment: It's the default theme loading for a second before displaying the splash screen. It gives a flickering effect.